# How do privileges work?

Tags: support, privileges

I've just got a notification "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – edit community wiki" (on Stack Overflow) and would like to know, which "event" has "triggered" this. In normal/"non-nerd" words: How do privileges work and how are different privileges awarded? Is there a list/sheet for this somewhere, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) for badges?

Comment: You mean like: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you earn 100 reputation, you gain [edit community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) privilege. All privileges are listed on `sitename.com/privileges`. E.g. for Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've overlooked the list on the right side of the priveleges page...